How to extract message using logstash filter functionality for the below Format
I am new to filters with logstash, here is the format of the log,
{"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 0, "d": 0 } { success: True, score: 0 }
{"a": 6, "b": 2, "c": 0, "d": 0 } { success: False, score: 0 }

Please help to provide your support to fix the filter condition.
